Is GetLastError() sticky?
Is GetLastError() sticky, i.e. the error code isn't modified until an error actually happens ? Or do Win32-functions set the last error code to ERROR_SUCCESS (0) for any successful operation ?

It's somewhat all over the place. Some APIs always set last error, some only if an error occurs. Generally you should only call GetLastError() if the API fails and is documented to set last error.

It is also not uncommon for a function to call a helper function that calls SetLastError() to report an error, then the function recovers from the error and ultimately succeeds, leaving a leftover error code behind.

@Luke "if the API fails and is documented to set last error" - The shorter version is more accurate: "if the API is documented to set [the] last error". There isn't much more to say than to consult the documentation, for every API call made.

This is specific to per function. As GetLastError says, Some functions call SetLastError with a zero when they succeed, wiping out the error code set by the most recently failed function. You should call the GetLastError function immediately when a function's return value indicates that such a call will return useful data.

GetLastError() returns the value set through the most recent call to SetLastError() (or the awkward1 RestoreLastError()) on the calling thread. It doesn't otherwise change.
API calls document under which conditions they call SetLastError(). Most APIs do not reset the last error code to ERROR_SUCCESS on successful execution.

1 Why is there a RestoreLastError function that does the same thing as SetLastError?

GetLastError() is "sticky" only until something decides to call SetLastError() for any reason.
Many APIs call SetLastError() only on failure.
Some APIs call SetLastError() on success, too.
Many APIs don't call SetLastError() at all. Or call it indirectly via their own internal calls.
There is no consistent pattern to it. So, you must consult the documentation for every function you are interested in performing error checking for, to see how it reports errors, and what conditions are expected to set the error code if at all.
